# How to monitor traffic from domains forwarding?

Tags: domains, google-analytics, dns

I have suppose 10 domains all redirecting( using godaddy forwarding) to example.com. Is there a way I can monitor traffic from these 10 domains ? Probably some how in Google Analytics or some other way out ? I am using Google Analytics on example.com

Answer (score 5):

You will want to use [forwarding](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/422/forwarding-or-masking-your-domain-name) to configure your redirects.

When you enter the target URL in the "Forward To" field, you can put the target URL plus some parameters that GA will read so you can treat the forward just like any other campaign:

- http://www.targetUrl.com/?utm_medium=redirect&utm_source=oldUrl1&utm_campaign=GoDaddyRedirect

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would want to do something along the [lines of this](http://www.lanevance.com/web/web-development/tracking-301-redirects-with-google-analytics/), to keep a 301 redirect (for SEO purposes) while still capturing the needed information in Analytics

I doubt using godaddy redirects would let you customise this properly.

Comment: godaddy do 301 redirects only. If I dont use re-directs using godaddy; its a very tedious process to maintain 30 domains individually.